# Function declaration - Keyword codeigniter3

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I've read other posts here that

```
public function login(){

}
```

and

```
function login(){

}
```

are the same. With the keyword its public, without it's assumed as public.

I'm making a small project, i'm trying to do user authentications as there are 3 types of users for me so different **access_level**.

My question is that, almost all of my functions are declared as public, in my controls and models.

Is this good practice? or should i declare them as protected(so only that class in which the function was declared can use).

In some part of me, i understand that declaring them all as public may not be the best but then again, i have no experience in the effects of this so there's no weight to that knowledge.

It's like when you tell a kid not to play with firecrackers or else they'll lose their fingers, they will listen but won't put much emphasis as they have no 'scary' experience to base it from.

just to add, i have MY_Controller in my core folder, 
if i were to declare the functions there as protected, does it restrict me in any way from calling the functions there from other controllers?

Also, for example,

```
function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
$this->auth['result'] = $this->is_logged_in();
}
```

Do i also declare a keyword for construct function? like,

```
public function __construct(){}
```

Comment: a good rule of thumb is only to expose what is absolutely necessary

Comment: They are called **Access Modifiers** and *public* is the basically the definition of how the function be accessed by other objects. It's the matter of accessibility/visibility: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php